# Alternate to ajaxSetup in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I am currently working in angular js. I have a controller and service layers to process all AJAX calls (i.e. all GET, PUT and so on...).
I have written all the API calls (http GET, PUT...) in service layer and calling them from the controller, Now I have a query that, what if I need to check the session status before each AJAX call What do I need to do?
Like if an user is logged out then his session is obviously expired, then suppose in this case user hits the back button of the browser he should remain on the login screen only, I have written some server side code to check it, And I used to call it via jQuery[in my previous project].
the code I used to use is as follows,'

```
$.ajaxSetup({
statusCode:{
901:function(){ window.location.replace("./logout"; }
}
});
```

But How can I implement the same in angular js.
Please help..!!

Comment: Use `httpinterceptors`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors in combination with the `$http` service instead of jquery's ajax calls

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Check the official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation but did not understand much. Can you give me any live example, I would provide my code if you want

Answer (score 0):

```
module.run(function($http) {
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the interceptor as a service

```
  $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
      // optional method
      'request': function(config) {
        // do something on success
        return config;
      },

      // optional method
     'requestError': function(rejection) {
        // do something on error
        if (canRecover(rejection)) {
          return responseOrNewPromise
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      },



      // optional method
      'response': function(response) {
        // do something on success
        return response;
      },

      // optional method
     'responseError': function(rejection) {
        // do something on error
        if (canRecover(rejection)) {
          return responseOrNewPromise
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  });
```